# How to extract features and target from opus/medical using tensorflow.dataset based on 'mnist' example on tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to learn something more about the use of tensorflow datasets, I'm really new.
I'm trying to work with the open/medical dataset for a NLP translation exercise from 'en' to 'de'
I have downloaded the dataset:

```
train_ds,ds_info= tfds.load('opus/medical',split=['train'], as_supervised = True, with_info = True)
```

ask for ds_info information

```
enter ctfds.core.DatasetInfo(
name='opus',
version=0.1.0,
description='OPUS is a collection of translated texts from the web.
```

Create your own config to choose which data / language pair to load.

```
config = tfds.translate.opus.OpusConfig(
    version=tfds.core.Version('0.1.0'),
    language_pair=("de", "en"),
    subsets=["GNOME", "EMEA"]
)
builder = tfds.builder("opus", config=config)
```

```
medical documents',
    homepage='http://opus.nlpl.eu/',
    features=Translation({
        'de': Text(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
        'en': Text(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
    }),
    total_num_examples=1108752,
    splits={
        'train': 1108752,
    },
    supervised_keys=('de', 'en'),
    citation="""@inproceedings{Tiedemann2012ParallelData,
      author = {Tiedemann, J},
      title = {Parallel Data, Tools and Interfaces in OPUS},
      booktitle = {LREC}
      year = {2012}}""",
    redistribution_info=,
)ode here
```

Now I would like to use 'en' as feature text srting and 'de' as target text string.
Following mnist example:

```
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train')
ds = ds.take(1)  # Only take a single example

for example in ds:  # example is `{'image': tf.Tensor, 'label': tf.Tensor}`
  print(list(example.keys()))
  image = example["image"]
  label = example["label"]
  print(image.shape, label)
```

but it seems not possible:

```
train_ds1 = train_ds.take(1)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'take'
```

but with opus/medical it seems impossible.
II point: I would like to configure the opus/medical to use 'en' and 'it', I have tried in different way without success.
Now I have used

```
   `config = tfds.translate.opus.OpusConfig(
    version=tfds.core.Version('0.1.0'),
    language_pair=("en", "it"),
    subsets=["GNOME", "EMEA"])
builder = tfds.builder("opus", config=config)`
 and I have downloaded the 'en' 'it' version.
```

But if try:

```
    for a in train_ds:
    print(a)
```

THE result is: train. and really I don't understand how to fetch the data.
Someone could help me?
Thanks